# Implementing non-blocking remote logging handler

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, logging

I'm trying to implement simple log handler that uses Python's standard `logging` library to log events to remote server. So I created custom class inherited from `logging.Handler` called `RemoteLogHandler` that accepts `LogRecord` and sends it to remote server. The handler is attached to root logger in standard `addHandler()` manner.

```
from urllib import requests

class RemoteLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        remote_url = "http://foo.bar.baz"
        req = request.Request(remote_url, data=record.msg)
        request.urlopen(req, timeout=1)
```

This works as intended, but can obviously cause locking of the calling thread when the remote_url becomes inaccessible or starts responding slowly. So I'm trying to figure best way to make this call independent on the calling thread.

What I've considered:

1. Including some non-standard library that would make the http request asynchronous
2. Using QueueHandler and QueueListener as outlined [here](http://plumberjack.blogspot.cz/2010/09/improved-queuehandler-queuelistener.html)
3. Using asyncio

All these solutions seem to be way too complex/unnecessary for achieving such simple task. Is there some better approach with less overhead in order to make this handler non-blocking?

Comment: Your app shouldn't be routing its logs anywhere, see e.g. https://12factor.net/logs

Comment: Why do you believe that the queuing solution is an overcomplication? It is the only solution here: a worker thread that pushes the records remotely, and the normal thread(s) that add the records to the queue when emitting them.

Comment: You can also switch to the UDP traffic, and just send the datagrams in the emitting method, non-blocking. But there will be no guarantee of delivery and processing remotely (syslog handler works that way, afaik).

Comment: You were right, I ended up using QueueHandler/Listener from logging package and it turned out to be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone who will face this, the solution turned out to be simple as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block).

```
import queue
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener

# instantiate queue & attach it to handler
log_queue = queue.Queue(-1)
queue_handler = QueueHandler(log_queue)

# instantiate our custom log handler (see question)
remote_handler = RemoteLogHandler()

# instantiate listener
remote_listener = QueueListener(log_queue, remote_handler)

# attach custom handler to root logger
logging.getLogger().addHandler(queue_handler)

# start the listener
remote_listener.start()
```

QueueListener runs in its own thread and listens to LogRecords that are sent by QueueHandlers which results in non-blocking logging.